# How do I get an Iframe to scroll down like movie credits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an Iframe that loops through an array of published Google sheets.  Is there a way that I can have the iframe scroll down over time to display all the data from the published URLs?

Ideally, I would like to get the results sheets to start from the top and over 30 seconds, scroll down to the bottom, then when at the bottom, switch to the next results sheet.  This would then continually loop from Site 1 to Site 5.

Here is my code:

```js
    var sites = [
      "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gd4eYAukSIvU0VS_zt37TWNiKi15-lB3V8f5AA3IXJU/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true",
      "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gd4eYAukSIvU0VS_zt37TWNiKi15-lB3V8f5AA3IXJU/pubhtml?gid=1991236368&single=true",
      "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gd4eYAukSIvU0VS_zt37TWNiKi15-lB3V8f5AA3IXJU/pubhtml?gid=205619546&single=true",
      "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gd4eYAukSIvU0VS_zt37TWNiKi15-lB3V8f5AA3IXJU/pubhtml?gid=1480439822&single=true",
      "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gd4eYAukSIvU0VS_zt37TWNiKi15-lB3V8f5AA3IXJU/pubhtml?gid=1101347808&single=true"

    ];
    var currentSite = sites.length;

    $(document).ready(function() {
      var $iframe = $("iframe").attr("src", "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gd4eYAukSIvU0VS_zt37TWNiKi15-lB3V8f5AA3IXJU/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true");
      setInterval(function() {
        (currentSite == 1) ? currentSite = sites.length - 1: currentSite = currentSite - 1;
        $iframe.attr("src", sites[currentSite]);
      }, 10000);
    });
```

```css
    iframe {
      height: 768px;
      width: 1024px;
      border: 2px solid gray;
    }
    body {
      width: 1024px;
      length: 768px;
      background-color: #C9C9C9;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #heading-wrapper {
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: #FF6600;
      border: 2px solid black;
      text-align: center;
      width: 1024px;
    }
    #heading-wrapper h1 {
      font-family: Arial;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <title>Live Results</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="heading-wrapper">
    <h1>Live Results</h1>
  </div>
  <iframe></iframe>
</body>
```

I don't even know if it is possible to have it scroll slowly down.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

```
iframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(x, y);
```

You could create a function that calls that periodically with an incremented y scroll amount.

Answer (score 0):

use set interval and change the scrollTop property of your containing element:

```
setInterval(changeScrollPosition, 50); // every 50 milliseconds

function changeScrollPosition(el)
{
    var currentTop = el.scrollTop;
    el.scrollTop = currentTop + howMuchYouWantToScrollBy;
}
```